# jquery scroll stops scrolling in 90% of the scrolling area (only) on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, scroll

I am using http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scroll/demos.php?demo=vt, because I have a non-scrollable page with scrollable rectangle in the middle. I don't need scrollbar, only mouswheel, that's why I have overflow:hidden - the example html from the page:

```
    <style type="text/css">
/* NOTE: width and height for div#wn also specified in scroll_v.css */
div#wn  { 
    position:relative; 
    width:250px; height:170px;
    overflow:hidden; /* for non-javascript */
    }
/* NOTE: styles for code are in external css file named scroll_v.css.
Script segment below writes link tag. */
</style>
<script src="js/dw_scroll_c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function init_dw_Scroll() {
    // arguments: id of scroll area div, id of content div
    var wndo = new dw_scrollObj('wn', 'lyr1');

}

// if code supported, link in the style sheet (optional) and call the init function onload
if ( dw_scrollObj.isSupported() ) {
    dw_Util.writeStyleSheet('css/scroll_v.css');
    dw_Event.add( window, 'load', init_dw_Scroll);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Vertical Mouseover Scrolling</h1>



<div id="wn"> <!-- scroll area div -->
    <div id="lyr1"> <!-- layer in scroll area (content div) -->
        <p>This example demonstrates vertical scrolling using mouseover links. Speed doubles on mousedown.</p>
        <p>Scroll links could also be setup for mousedown scrolling if you prefer.</p>

        <p>Content repeated for your scrolling pleasure :)</p>

        <p>This example demonstrates vertical scrolling using mouseover links. Speed doubles on mousedown.</p>
        <p>Scroll links could also be setup for mousedown scrolling if you prefer.</p>

    </div> <!-- end content div (lyr1) -->
</div>  <!-- end wn div -->
```

(I won't give all js file because it is large and it is on the link before code, If someone want to see this dw_scroll_c.js file directly, I can link it, but it is very unfriendly to read because they removed all spaces in the code.)

So this scroll works perfectly, but only when my content in lyr1 is not so long - maybe for 2000px it works fine, but If I have a large amount on text and pictures - it stops scrolling somewhere in the middle.
For tests - when I delete something 200px before this stop-boundary, it stops scrolling 200px further if we are looking on the text (so this stop-boundary doesn't depend on data).

**Edit**
I split my content for two scrollable areas. Now I can't scroll both to the end. I can scroll maybe 90% of them. When I had one scrollable area I could scroll it maybe to 90%, it was hard to calculate, but now I can see that.

The thing is happening only on IE-8, on ff 11, Chrome and IE-9 all the page is scrollable.
What do I need to look for and change in js file to make my page all scrollable in IE-8?